# Python PyQt QWebView to PDF - Image Not Loading

Tags: python, html, pdf, pyqt

I currently have images in HTML string format like this:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAT0AAAGQCAIAAABTeyD6AAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/......(cut here).....QZBnijNOpmMG2HY2FPO3I11PkGNcMmV
```

I'm trying to create a PDF using QWebView and QPrinter

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView
import os

FN = os.path.join("Image.pdf")
HTML_FILE = file containing html string

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
view = QWebView()
view.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
view.setAttribute(Qt.WA_OpaquePaintEvent, False)
page = view.page()
palette = page.palette()
palette.setBrush(QPalette.Base, Qt.transparent)
page.setPalette(palette)
page.currentFrame().documentElement().setInnerXml("text")
view.setHtml(HTML_FILE)
printer = QPrinter()
printer.setOutputFileName(FN)
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
printer.setPageMargins(15, 15, 15, 15, QPrinter.Millimeter)
view.print_(printer)
```

When I write as HTML file, it works perfect and the image is displayed but when I export it as a PDF using QWebKit, the image isn't displayed. I'm not very good at HTML but I've been trying all combinations to make this work, unsuccessfully. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!